# How to replicate a String in a dataframe individually N times

Tags: r, replicate

I have a dataframe and I want to replicate the input of a single cell n times dependent on the input of the next cell and display it in a new cell.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4), c("A","B","A","C","D","E","A"), c(2,1,1,3,2,1,3))
colnames(data) <- c("document number", "term", "count")
data
```

This is my desired result:

```
datanew <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4), c("A A B", "A", "C C C", "D D E A A A"))
colnames(datanew) <- c("document number", "term")


#   document number        term
# 1               1       A A B
# 2               2           A
# 3               3       C C C
# 4               4 D D E A A A
```

So basically, I like to multiplicate the input of the term cell with the input of the corresponding count cell. Does anyone has an idea how to code it in R?

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rep` to replicate `term` `count` times and `paste` the data together.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(`document number`) %>%
  summarise(new = paste(rep(term, count), collapse = " "))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  `document number` new        
#              <dbl> <chr>      
#1                 1 A A B      
#2                 2 A          
#3                 3 C C C      
#4                 4 D D E A A A
```

Similarly with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, (new =  paste(rep(term, count), collapse = " ")), 
               by = `document number`]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `tidyverse` methods

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
   uncount(count) %>%
   group_by(`document number`) %>% 
   summarise(term = str_c(term, collapse=' '))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  `document number` term       
#              <dbl> <chr>      
#1                 1 A A B      
#2                 2 A          
#3                 3 C C C      
#4                 4 D D E A A A
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[rep(seq_len(.N), count)][, .(term = 
        paste(term, collapse=' ')), `document number`]
```

---

Or using `base R` with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(term ~ `document number`, data[rep(seq_len(nrow(data)), 
           data$count),], FUN = paste, collapse= ' ')
```